# Trigger Upddate On Another Object

Tags: trigger

```
trigger DealSheetUpdate on Change_Log__c(after update) {
    List < DealSheet__c > DealSheet1 = new List < DealSheet__c > ();
    List < String > IdChange = new List < String > ();
    Map < String, Dealsheet__c > DealSheet = new map < String, Dealsheet__c > ();
    for (Dealsheet__c deals: [select name, CP_P_O_CODE__c from Dealsheet__c where name =: Change_Log__c.name]) {
        IdChange.add(deals.name);
        DealSheet.put(deals.name, deals);
    }
    for (Change_Log__c log: newlist) {
        List < DealSheet__c > Deal = new List < DealSheet__c > ();
        deal.CP_P_O_CODE__c = log.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;
        Change.add(deal);
    }
    try {
        Update DealSheet1;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

i have 2 objects. `DealSheet__c` and `Change_Logg__c`.

when ever `DealSheet__c` updated, old records are saving in `Change_Log__c` for that after Update trigger is there in `DealSheet__c`. Now my requirement is if we Change the field values in `Change_log__c` then they should be Update in `DealSheet__c`. there is no relationship b/n two objects. Dealsheet name is autonumber is same name in `Change_Log__c`.

Thanking u

Comment: Are you getting an error? This code looks like it's updating Deal Sheets when the Change Log is changed.

Comment: ya i am trying that

Comment: i am getting error"Didn't understand relationship 'Change_Log__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your code. Please use the below code:

**SOLUTION:**

```
    trigger DealSheetUpdate on Change_Log__c(after update){  

    Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
    List<Dealsheet__c> dealSheetList = new List<Dealsheet__c>();


    for(Change_Log__c cLog : trigger.new){
        names.add(cLog.Name);
    }

    Map<String,Dealsheet__c> DealSheet = new map<String,Dealsheet__c>();

    for(Dealsheet__c deals : [Select Name,CP_P_O_CODE__c  from Dealsheet__c where name IN: names ]){
          DealSheet.put(deals.name, deals);
    }  

    for(Change_Log__c log : trigger.new){

         Dealsheet__c dSheet = DealSheet.get(log.Name);
         if( dSheet!=null){
          dSheet.CP_P_O_CODE__c = log.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;
          dealSheetList.add(dSheet);
        }         
    }


  try{
    Update dealSheetList;
  }
   catch(Exception e)
   { } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39987/discussion-on-answer-by-iamsfdc-trigger-upddate-on-another-object).